How to exclude a specific folder when merging branches in Git?
I have a Git repository with three branches: develop, staging, and main. My current workflow is as follows:

Create feature branches out of develop and squash merge feature branches back into develop.
Merge develop into staging using rebase and fast forward.
Merge staging into main using rebase and fast forward.

Currently, the branches look like this:
Branch develop:
repo/
  research/
    file0.py
  src/
    file1.py
    file2.py
    file3.py

Branch staging:
repo/
  research/
    file0.py
  src/
    file1.py
    file2.py
    file3.py

Branch main:
repo/
  research/
    file0.py
  src/
    file1.py
    file2.py
    file3.py

I want to retain this workflow but ensure that the research folder exists only in the develop branch. When merging from develop into staging, the research folder should be ignored.
Additional requirements:

The existing research folders on staging and main should be removed.

The main branch should not be ahead of staging and staging should not be ahead of develop. That means that the merge from develop into staging and from staging into main should not create new commits.


The branches should look like this:
Branch develop:
repo/
  research/
    file0.py
  src/
    file1.py
    file2.py
    file3.py

Branch staging:
repo/
  src/
    file1.py
    file2.py
    file3.py

Branch main:
repo/
  src/
    file1.py
    file2.py
    file3.py

How can I achieve this? Detailed steps would be appreciated.

You're using staging and main as deployment targets. You can easily enough bludgeon Git into simple deployment service like this. If you want to deploy some commit without that content put research/* export-ignore in .gitattributes and deploy it with git archive @ | tar Cxf path/to/deploy - or any equivalent but actual help is going to require details. The content's available to anyone who has the repo. What specific need led you to devise this attempt at meeting it?

This question is similar to: How to make git ignore a directory while merging. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Like @ManjunathKaramudi said: look at the accepted answer on that question and change merge to merge --squash.

If you want the directory research to only exist in a branch named develop,  just add a pre-commit hook that rejects any attempt to create that directory unless the current branch is named develop.  (If it already exists in the other branches, you'll want/need to delete it from them.)

@WilliamPursell Could you please provide an example? Specifically, what would happen if a commit includes changes to both the research folder and the src directory? Would such a commit be rejected? If so, at what stage would the rejection occur? Would it be during the merge of develop into staging?

Since anyone who has the repo can check out the other branches and see the research data it's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve here. "For audit reasons", what exactly are your auditors trying to prevent? Not in repository terms, in business requirement terms. Exactly what or who must be prevented from seeing this data? Because what you're asking for won't prevent any such thing.

You can back up your research folder, remove it from develop, merge this into staging and then master, then branch out from develop a test branch where you put research back and push it. Step-by-step:

git checkout develop
move research out from develop
commit and push your changes
git checkout staging
git merge develop
git push
git checkout master
git merge staging
git push
git checkout develop
git branch test
git checkout test
copy research back to test
push it

So you will always be able to branch out from develop a feature branch, squash merge test into your feature branch and when you are ready to create a PR, remove the squash merge so your research folder will not get into develop, staging or master. Of course, if research changes, you will need to either commit directly to test or branch out a test branch from it.

Solution 1:
Since you don't want to have Research folder in stage and main branch. You can manually checkout to those branch and delete that folder each time you merge with develop branch.
Alternative Solution 2:
An alternative solution is to remove the research folder from the develop branch itself and keep it offline in you local machine only. You can achieve this by creating a .gitignore file and add research/ to that file. This way your research folder wont be tracked by git anymore and you can keep it offline with you.
Alternative Solution 3:
Another way would be - while merging from develop to stage branch, you can cherry pick the commits which does not include changes from research folder.

@StamatisTiniakos do you want me to write the commands also?


Switch to staging and remove the research folder. git rm -r research
Merge develop into staging. git merge --ff-only develop
Switch to main and remove the research folder. git rm -r research
Merge staging into main. git merge --ff-only staging

For better understanding of --ff-only option, check out the git documentation.
Solution 2:
You can set up a .gitattributes file to specify that changes in the research directory should always take precedence from develop when merging into staging.
Add this line to .gitattributes file and make sure to commit it:
research/* merge=ours

Then you can just merge by switching to staging or main and execute: git merge develop.
Research folder will be ignored.
git checkout staging # or main
git merge develop


This is a good start and explains how to delete the research folder from the existing staging and main branches. However, it doesn't address how to prevent changes in the research directory in develop from merging into staging. We need a mechanism that ensures any changes in the research directory remain in develop and do not propagate to staging.

You can set up a .gitattributes file to specify that changes in the research directory should always take precedence from develop when merging into staging.
.gitattributes
research/* merge=ours

Please add these steps in your answer. I will test it and if it works happy to approve your answer.

I added as solution 2
